# Excepción al convertir a JSON un hash md5

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, django, md5

Estoy haciendo una llamada por ajax a otro servicio en la que me piden pasar unos valores por MD5 para enviárselos. Realizo el hash con la librería haslib y obtengo un objeto hash. Mi problema es que al pasarlo por ajax me da el siguiente error:

> b'\xb8\xadE\xdc\xb98\x1a\xa9|\xe7\\x17\x8dD\xaal' is not JSON serializable

Mi código es este:

```
session = request.COOKIES['sessionid']+str(datetime.now().microsecond)
hash = hashlib.md5(session.encode('utf-8')).digest()
```

El error se puede reproducir si se intenta convertir ese hash a json, por ejemplo así:

```
resultado = json.dumps({"md5": hash})
```

Comment: Qué linea exacta arroja el error, puedes mostrar mas detalles? Por ahora luce como que no puedes serializar bytes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El método `digest` devuelve el hash en forma de secuencia de bytes. El siguiente código muestra un sencillo ejemplo que se puede ejecutar desde un intérprete estándar, sin necesidad de tener django o el resto de tu aplicación:

```
import hashlib

session = "supongamos que esto es el sessionid"
hash = hashlib.md5(session.encode('utf-8')).digest()
print(hash)
```

Mostrará algo como:

```
b'T\x95\xf7\x04P\x1blE)\x0e\xee\x89)\xe6\xf4+'
```

Esta es la forma en que python3 representa una secuencia de bytes. La `b` inicial indica que no es una cadena normal, sino de bytes. En su interior pueden aparecer bytes que se decodifiquen como ASCII (como la `T` inicial) y otros que no serían ASCII válido (como el `\x95` que sigue, que representa un byte de valor hexadecimal `95`).

Este tipo de cadenas binarias no pueden ser convertidas en JSON, ya que JSON permite sólo cadenas con caracteres UNICODE válidos.

Lo habitual cuando se quiere enviar como JSON un hash, es usar su representación hexadecimal, que sería una cadena ASCII que contiene sólo los caracteres `0`--`9` y `a`--`f`.

El módulo `hashlib` puede producirte una cadena así con el método `hexdigest()`. Por ejemplo:

```
import hashlib

session = "supongamos que esto es el sessionid"
hash = hashlib.md5(session.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
print(hash)
```

Muestra:

```
5495f704501b6c45290eee8929e6f42b
```

Observa que ahora el resultado es ya una cadena normal y en ella todo son caracteres ascii, pero de algún modo representa la misma información ya que el `54` inicial es el ASCII de la `T`, el `95` siguiente sería el byte `\x95`, etc.

Ahora no tendrás problema al serializarlo como json:

```
import json

resultado = json.dumps({"md5": hash})
print(resultado)
```

Y saldría:

```
{"md5": "5495f704501b6c45290eee8929e6f42b"}
```